# Use compiled gcc to compile my code, but cannot found certain header files

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I compiled gcc9 from source, and used default install prefix:

```
./configure --disable-mutilib
make -j16
make install
```

After that, I found the gcc version is updated:

```
which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 9.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

However, when I use it in my code:

```
#include <filesystem>
....
```

I compiled it with cmake as I used default system gcc:

```
mkdir -p build
cmake ..
make
```

I got the errors of:

/root/cpp/main_demo.cpp:17:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
...

I am sure the file `filesystem` exists in my install path, since I can find it with `find /usr/local -iname '*filesystem*'.

What did I miss and how could I make it work?

Comment: Are you sure you're using C++17?

Comment: Also, GCC 9 [seems to not support filesystem completely](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.htm).

Comment: Yes, I used gcc9 docker image, and found that I can compile well. And I used the makefile generated by gcc9 docker image, it can also work. but I cannot make it work from scratch without use docker image.